# Pass the JSON Data Between From Controller To another Controller with out using Services or Factory in angular JS while Routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have Object in `Dashboard` page, When Click on `Details` Page From Dash Board it should redirect to `Details` page, I want Pass the **JSON** Object From `Dashboard Controller` to `Details Controller`, Is there any way With out using `Angular JS` Service or `factory`.

```
myApp.controller('dashBoardController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

     $scope.detailsPage = function(Object){


     // I want this object available in details page controller

        $location.path('/detailsPage');
};

}]);

myApp.controller('detailsOageController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  //  need Object data here
}]);
```

Comment: So, the recommended way to do it is with a service.  Understanding why you don't want to follow the framework's preferred method would help folks answer you.

Comment: Service would be the most elegant way, by far! Another way would be by using a pub/sub design pattern to send a message from dashboardController and listen for it within the detailsOageController, it would work but it's not that nice though :-)

Comment: you could use $rootScope, but it's a really bad practice that might cost you trouble in the long run. Services should be the best way to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve data sharing from one controller to another by below methods.

1. Using service/factory(mostly preferred)
2. Using Rootscope and values will be in Global scope(Not advicable)
3. Emit & Broadcast

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope